# get filtered documents after comparing specific field of 2 embedded documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i construct a collection of time table for trains and i want to give my function departure station and arrival station then the function should return the trains that match criteria

this is one document of my collection

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "train_id": 1,
  "train_type": "VIP",
  "stations": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "times": [
    {
      "station_id": 1,
      "order": 1,
      "time": "05:00",
      "days": [
        "sun",
        "mon",
        "wed"
      ]
    },
    {
      "station_id": 2,
      "order": 2,
      "time": "07:00",
      "days": [
        "sun",
        "mon",
        "thu",
        "wed"
      ]
    },
    {
      "station_id": 3,
      "order": 3,
      "time": "08:00",
      "days": [
        "sun",
        "mon",
        "thu"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so i want to get the trains that should go through station 1 and station 3 and the order of station 1 should be lower than the order of station 3 
using normal find or aggregate framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Aggregation Framework to achieve this. The [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) will do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match : {"stations" : {$all : [1, 3]}} // This to make sure that the contains all the arrival and departure stations 
},
{
    "$addFields" : { // With this you'll get 2 new fields if the "$times" array contains them
        "departureObject" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$times", { $indexOfArray: [ "$times.station_id", 1 ] } ]},
        "arrivalObject" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$times", { $indexOfArray: [ "$times.station_id", 3 ] } ]}

    }
},
{
    $match: {$expr: {$gt: ["$arrivalObject.order", "$departureObject.order"]}} // This is to ensure that the arrival station is after departure station 
}
]);
```

Checkout [MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C-zgpiqIDi3) with the example.